# Incremental load in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, incremental-load, dynamic-mapping

I am replicating my data from Azure SQl DB TO Azure SQL DB. I have some tables with date columns and some tables  with just the ID columns which are assigning primary key. While performing incremental load in ADF, I can select date as watermark column for the tables which have date column and id as watermark column for the tables which has id column, But the issue is my id has guid values, So can I i take that as my watermark column ? and if yes while copy activity process it gives me following error in ADF

Please see the image for above reference

[image: Please see the image for above reference]

How can I overcome this issue. Help is appreciated

Thank you
Gp

I have tried dynamic mapping https://martinschoombee.com/2022/03/22/dynamic-column-mapping-in-azure-data-factory/ from here but it does not work it still gives me same error.

Comment: Is copy activity failing only during incremental copy?

Comment: can you show your dynamic mapping output and data types of the underlying source and sink columns?

Comment: @Aswin yes it fails during copy activity

Comment: @Geezer the data types at both source and sink are uniqueidentifier and the value which I was passing for column mapping parameter was : 
{"type": "TabularTranslator","mappings": [{"source": {"name": "RKey","type": "guid"},{"sink": {"name": "RKey","type": "String"}}]}

Comment: What is the datatype and constraints in Sink SQL table for id column?

Comment: @Aswin its guid at sink and ideally constraint should be primary key but during auto creation table through adf primary key is not being set on the id column

Comment: @Gauri if the datatype in source is `uniqueidentifier` then why are using `String` datatype in sink the mapping?

Comment: @Geezer I was trying to test it, but I did try keeping same datatype i.e. guid at both sides, still it fails. I have created paramater columnmapping with type object and in the copy activity I have added mapping as @pipeline().parameters.ColumnMappping

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question about watermak:
**A watermark is a column that has the last updated time stamp or an incrementing key**
So GUID column would not be a good fit.
Try to find a date column, or an integer identity which is ever incrementing, to use as watermark.
Since your source is SQL server, you can also use change data capture.
Links:
[Incremental loading in ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview)
[Change data capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Regards,
Chen

Comment: is there any documentation where I can go through the cons of using guid as watermark column ?

Comment: The link I wrote above shows what are good candidate for a watermark column. I don't think guid can be used.

Answer (score 0):

The watermark logic takes advantange of the fact that all the new records which are inserted after the last watermark saved should only be considered for copying from source A to B , basically we are using ">=" operator to our advantage here .

In case of guid you cannot use that logic as guid cann surely be unique but not ">=" or "=<" will not work.

Comment: that is true, I agree on that point, but I dont have any other column in the table on which I can set incremental load other than the guid , is there any workaround for this other than CT or CDC

Comment: How big is the table ? What is the incremental growth we are are looking in terms of record count ?

Comment: At the moment table is not big, records are less than lakhs but the size can increase later

Comment: is there any way out for this as the CT approach would not work in my case due to some restrictions

Comment: A far fetched Idea and let me be honest never tried in practice . 
A uniqueidentifier (GUID) contains text, so it's only logical that you cannot convert it directly to an INT. What you can do is create a mapping table. Generate your GUID and insert it into a table containing an IDENTITY column . Basically you join the mapping table on the GUID and use INT as an watermark . Good luck ;)